# Glassfish persisting HTTP Sessions into database

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, glassfish, httpsession, session-management

I need a way to configure Java HTTP Sessions to be stored into a common/centralized database, regardless of performance.

Is there anyway to achieve this using web.xml or glassfish-web.xml? How can I do it?

Comment: May I ask why? Your best bet may be to offload your sessions to a distributed cache. E.g. Payara Server is derived from GlassFish and has the ability to store sessions in a Hazelcast cache, meaning that you can stand up completely separate Hazelcast nodes to join the cluster. I can't see any benefit in persisting sessions to disk, so I'm still curious what your actual goal is.

Comment: The ultimate goal is exactly what you were saying. At the moment I need to persist sessions in a common storage ASAP, whether it is disk or RAM.

In a later stage that would be a distributed cache like memcached or whatever is suitable.

Comment: In that case, I would go with a distributed cache or data grid first. There's nothing to be gained by introducing a database. [There's a video here about  using Hazelcast to do that sort of thing.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idifKBUhOsI) You could also use something like infinispan, coherence or ehcache for the same thing.

Comment: Either case, DB or distributed cache, can I share sessions between various Application Containers? Say the app will be deployed to Glassfish, WebLogic and any other stuff ?

Comment: In theory yes, but that's a very bad idea. Most obvious is the assumption that each container is going to serialise the session in the same way. What could happen in that case is that you just clog up the GlassFish session cache with WebLogic or JBoss sessions which it can't do anything with, meaning less room in the cache for actual GlassFish sessions.